# Interpolation - Vue.js class in css

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I interpolate classes in css with vue?

```js
{{ category.icon }} --> "icon1"
```

I want to be able to do:

```html
<i :class="category.icon" class="icon icon-"></i>
```

**This will output:**

```html
<i class="icon icon- icon1"></i>
```

How can I remove the spacing?

How is this achieved in vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want which space to be removed? Want to have `icon-icon1`?
Then go for

```js
:class="`icon-${category.icon}`"
```